# An equivalence relation on knots similar to concordance

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory, knot-link, seifert-surfaces

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two nonintersecting picewise-linear or smooth knots in $\mathbb R^3$. Suppose they are ambient isotopic. Does there exist an embedded surface $f: S^1\times[0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$  such that $L_1=f(\cdot,0)$ and  $L_2=f(\cdot,1)$. This is similar to concordance but stronger -- this "concordance" must be realised in $\mathbb R^3$ instead of $\mathbb R^3 \times [0,1]$.
If necessary, assume that $L_1,L_2$ are not linked or separated far from each other.

In other words is there a Seifert surface that is homeomorphic to a cylinder for a link consisting of two isotopic knots.

Comment: "If necessary, assume that $L_1$, $L_2$ are not linked or separated far from each other."  What does this sentence mean?

Comment: @SamNead $L_1$ sits in a ball $B_1$, $L_2$ sits in a ball $B_2$ and $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint.

Comment: This rarely ever occurs.  You realize all such pairs by taking a Seifert surface for a knot, then taking a parallel copy of the knot in the Seifert surface as your 2nd knot.  Perhaps this should be called the "parallel cable" of the knot.  I think the only time this generates an unlinked pair is when you start off with the unknot.

Comment: Take a knot, and another copy of the same knot far away. If they are not unknots, they do not cobound annuli (exercise).

Comment: @BrunoMartelli--Given the clarification by the OP, your comment seems to answer the question. Why don't you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a knot, and another copy of the same knot far away. It is then a nice instructive exercise to prove that if they are not unknots they do not cobound annuli.

Comment: thank you!

(take a plane that separates the first knot from the second one and intersect it with the annulus. move it, if necessary, to turn the intersection into a smooth submanifold. one of its connected components must be a circle that is non-trivial in the annulus. this component is by construction not tangled. shrink the annulus to a nontangled equator and untie -- this would give the triviality of the initial knot)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your question, the answer is "no".  Consider the Whitehead link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link

The two components of the Whitehead link are unknots (thus they are isotopic) but they do not cobound a cylinder.

---

Thank you for clarifying that you wish to assume that the given link is "split": the components are separated by a two-sphere.  In this case, the link is a "split unlink": a distant union of unknots.  As Bruno points out, this is an exercise.

Comment: the two components are linked though

Comment: @alesia The components of the Whitehead link are homologically unlinked... You are correct that Dmitry K assumed that the components are "are not linked or separated".  I found that sentence to be very confusing (as I pointed out).